# In official lore, what magic is forbidden in Strixhaven?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, lore, strixhaven

In both the *Strixhaven: A Curriculum of Chaos* D&D book and the Strixhaven *Magic: the Gathering* card flavour texts, forbidden magic is referenced. However, I can’t seem to find *what* is actually forbidden.

They seem to be fine with necromancy, as Lorehold college summons spirits, and cards like Moldering Karok feature undead living on or near Strixhaven campus.

The only things I was able to find was the flavour texts of a few cards:

> Strixhaven forbade all magic from the blood age…

(Plumb the Forbidden)

> This must not become common knowledge. The consequences of such a spell are too great. Lock it away in the restricted archive, and destroy its record in the catalog.

(Day of Judgement)

I can’t find anywhere that it specifies what magic was practiced in the blood age, however.

Comment: [Lightning Helix](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=517612) implies that at least some magics of the Blood Age aren’t forbidden, just forgotten, which contradicts the claim in Plumb the Depths that “all magic from the Blood Age” was forbidden. After all, it’s not as though [Lightning Bolt](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=191089) is *banned*, per se, they just tend not to include it in recent Standard sets because it’s considered too powerful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems vaguely to be:

- Blood-based magic (from all the enemies with an Oriq Mask from the Strixhaven sourcebook)
- Magic of [mass destruction](https://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=517552) / slaughter (from the STA Day of Judgment flavor text)
- Magic made for ["endless war"](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=517585), whatever that means (from the STA Village Rites flavor text)

It may be left ambiguous in the sourcebook so that you have the opportunity to make up evil spells, banned relics, or forbidden techniques in your game that your players encounter.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site... ***great*** first answer! Have you seen the [tour]? From your badges it looks like you might not have done so (you get a shiny badge). Also please do checkout the [help] as it should contain useful information!

Comment: While this is a good first answer having links to 3rd party sites isn't usually great so it is best to have some explanation in the answer itself. Both of the last bullet points make me wonder why fireball isn't banned, and what they think about meteor shower

Comment: @SeriousBri: I don't think there's an issue with the links themselves, but the answer should explain/quote the relevant parts of the linked pages so that the answer stands alone (e.g. in case the content of the linked pages is changed or removed).

Comment: @SeriousBri For the second point, think more "nuclear bomb" to *fireball*'s hand grenade.